# col-xs size is working in col-md size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my coding. In the paragraph tag col-xs-12 is working on medium device. And it is not taking the col-md-3 size.

```
<p class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> To what e-mail should we send the money?</p>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-8">
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="30" value="">
    </div>
```

Comment: insufficient information.
tell us what resolution are you trying to test that

Comment: Your code works just as expected and contains no errors. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htppjyxc/)

Comment: I do not see container class and row class or form-horizontal

Comment: though container and row class or recommend they are not required for the column widths

Comment: I am testing the above coding in the medium devices. I have used "col-md-4" class for div tag. But it is taking the width of "col-xs-8" in both xtra small device and medium device.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Full View: https://jsfiddle.net/riwakawebsitedesigns/bs22bkjt/5/embedded/result/

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/riwakawebsitedesigns/bs22bkjt/5/light/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" for=""> To what e-mail should we send the money?</label>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<input type="text" name="" value="" id="" class="form-control" />
</div>
</div>
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If 768px and under the label will show above input.